# Rails: preloading a has_many through relation in the controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax

I hope I can explain this clearly.

- A User has_many notifications and has_many movies through
  notifications. A movie has_many trailers.
- Notifications has 3 columns: user_id, movie_id, and website.
- On trailers#index, I am rendering @trailers and each @trailer renders
  3 x ajax notification_forms (each form is just a single button, one for
  each "website" option. When user clicks this button, an ajax request is sent to create a new notification record)
- I keep track of which buttons have been pressed (by looking up to see if a notification exists for that user/movie)

My concern is that because I'm only preloading the @trailers, I'm currently making 3 new DB calls on each iteration of a trailer.

_notification_form.html.erb (gets called 3 times on each trailer)

```
<% if trailer.movie.tracked?(current_user, "netflix") %>
   ## do some css stuff on the button to show notification already set
```

movie.rb:

```
def tracked?(user, website)
    user.notifications.where(movie_id: self.id, website: website).first
  end
```

So every time a trailer partial is rendered, I'm making 3 DB calls. What's the proper way to handle this situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're only checking the status of the `current_user` and every `Trailer` knows its `movie_id`, you can just load the `User`'s `Notification`s and check them for the `Trailer`s' `movie_id`s:

```
tracked = current_user.notifications
tracked.detect { |n| n.movie_id == trailer.movie_id && n.website == 'netflix' }
```

If a `User` might have a *ton* of `Notification`s, you can limit the set to only `Notification`s for the `Trailer`s on the page you're displaying:

```
tracked = current_user.notifications.where(movie_id: trailers.map(&:movie_id))
```

Load that up, and then just check it when you're deciding how to render your buttons. You can make it even more efficient by creating a `Set` containing `[movie_id, website]` pairs, which will do lookup in constant time.

```
tracked = Set.new(
  current_user.nofications
    .where(movie_id: trailers.map(&:movie_id))
    .pluck(:movie_id, :website)
)
tracked.include?([trailer.movie_id, 'netflix'])
```

This strategy will be fast for you because it's exactly tailored to the data you're checking. If you need something more flexible that still minimizes database queries, look into eagerly loading associations with [`includes`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods/includes), [`preload`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods/preload), and [`eager_load`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods/eager_load). [3 ways to do eager loading (preloading) in Rails 3 & 4](http://blog.arkency.com/2013/12/rails4-preloading/) has an excellent description of the differences between those methods. Those all work during your initial relation loading (that is, if you've not yet loaded anything), but when you've already loaded part of the data (eg, you have `Trailer`s but not `Movies`s or `Notification`s yet), you can use [ActiveRecord::Associations::Preloader](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Associations/Preloader) to efficiently load the rest.